# How to pass data from a parent view controller to its segmented control views in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I  have a view controller with three segmented view segments. each segment has containers. I want to pass data from the parent view to its segmented views..

```
class UserDetails: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var view3: UIView!
var id = "120"
```

i want to pass this variable "id" to view1

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    view1.hidden = false
    view2.hidden = true
    view3.hidden = true

    print(self.id)
 }
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

I want to pass variable id to view1..

Comment: You wil have to be more precise in what you want to do. Your view1 actually is just a view, do you want to display your id in it ?

Comment: you can pass the data through method `prepareForSegue`

Comment: Since "View1" is within the ViewController "UserDetails", there is no need to pass anything here. The value in "id" would be accessible from "View1"

Comment: thank u all for ur replies. @damien view1 is a container view, i want to pass id to that view

Comment: @KiranKV look like you don't understand what an UIView is, it can't get an id cause it has no specific attribute for an id, you should either extend uiview, or create a new uiview class, so you can give it an id. If you just want to display your id as a string in that view, then add a label inside of it. You really should be more explicit with what you are trying to do !